# Creating a file prior to initialization of a page

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, async-await, windows-10-universal

I inserted the following statement at the beginning of the code:

```
StorageFile file = await applicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("ImMerged.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

(in the constructor and in OnNavigatedTo method)

Before the Xaml page is loaded, I want to be certain that this file is created. Indeed I would like to use the file at the time of the loading of an image object. I already tried several methods.

- Change of the priority with Dispatcher,
- synchronous execution of an asynchronous method.

But the file handle is null just after.

Example:

```
 Task t = Task.Run(async () => {
            destinationFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("ImMerged.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        });
        t.Wait();
```

Some methods are no longer available like this one:

```
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { asyncOpenFile(options); });
```

Do you know if there is a way?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: have you tried using, `await Task.Run(() => DoWork());`?

Comment: Yes, and also with t.wait()

Comment: I add my code on Task.Run in my question. But the handle is null after t.Wait();

Comment: maybe there is something wrong in this part `CreateFileAsync`

Comment: If I manage the file in an async function, there is no problem with CreateFileAsync unless several methods execute the function at the same time.

Comment: Now it works! I restarted VS. I'm sorry.